# Show DIV during specific times of the day (eg., during store "open hours")

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to toggle `DIV` visibility based on time so my site shows when my physical store is open.

**For example:

 - 07:00-15:59 = Show div

 - 16:00-06:59 = Hide div**

Thanks!

Comment: For example, with JS: 1. Hide div via CSS. 2. Take current Date. 3. Calculate whether current hour is in "show hours". 4. If "yes" - show div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a basic example.

```
//gets the current time. 
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 15 ){
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {  
     $(".closed").show();
    $(".open").hide();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/16mnrL3b/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get system time:

```
    var date = new Date();

    var time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    $('div').hide()
    if(date.getHours()>7&&date.getHours()<16){
      $('div').show()
    }
    else 
    if(date.getHours()>=16&&date.getHours()<7){
      $('div').hide()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
if ( date('H:i') >= "07:00" && date('H:i') <= "16:00" ) {
   echo 'Time between 7 and 16';
}else{
   echo 'Time is runned out';
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I find this is enough even if my PHP aint the best :)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the current time with the time in which you need to show a specific div using jquery as follows:

```
$('#mydiv').hide();
$('#myclosediv').hide();

if(today.getHours() >= 7 && today.getHours() < 16){
 $('#myopendiv').show();
}   
else{
 $('#myclosediv').show();
}
```

If the current time is 7 AM to 4 PM, then the div with id 'myopendiv' will be shown. Else the other div.