# Display None on time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript code for a countdown timer. I want to use this code in a online shop order process. However I don't want to edit the date every day manually.

Now my question is: How can i display the div container from 6am to 2am (06.00 to 14.00).

From 14.00 to 06.00 i want that this container is display:none

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2018 18:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Bestellen Sie innerhalb der nächsten  <span style='font-size:18px;color: #008a00!important;'>" + hours + "&nbsp; Stunden und "
  + minutes + "&nbsp;Minuten " + "</span>und wir versenden noch am gleichen Tag!";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);


var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 18 ){
  $("#timer").show();
  $(".closed").hide();
} else {  
  $(".closed").show();
  $("#timer").hide();
}
```

```html
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="timer"></p>
<p class="closed"></p>
```

Have anyone a solution for that?

// Edit the post with new HTML/JS Data

Comment: I would handle this on the server, rather than on the client

Comment: Have you taken into account that anyone from around the globe might visit your page? So the time could change between visitors. You want it between 14:00 and 16:00 client time or server time?

Comment: How is the timer code shown related to the problem of hiding or showing a div?

Comment: This might help. Please check it out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776440/show-div-during-specific-times-of-the-dayuseful-for-showing-open-hours-on-web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776440/show-div-during-specific-times-of-the-dayuseful-for-showing-open-hours-on-web)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. We just have customers/visitors from germany etc. But we need the server time for that solution.

Comment: @niceoneishere Tahts worked for the first. But no i have a problem with my timezone. Yesterday we pushed the time 1 hour forward and have now summertime. localtime is now 15:52 When I set 16:00 in my counter the timer show me that there are 1 hour and 8 minutes left...